# Swift tableView delegate method is not getting called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have created a tableview controller but its delegate methods are not getting called. I referred a few web sites and didn't came across any mistake in my code. Please help me.

```
class FriutsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var fruitsList : [AnyObject] = ["We", "love", "swift"];

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myCatalog = Catalog()
    fruitsList = myCatalog.fruits;
    //let view = ViewController()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruitsList.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("fruitIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell

    if !cell {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "fruitIdentifier")
    }

    cell!.textLabel.text = fruitsList[indexPath.row] as AnyObject! as String!
    return cell
}

@objc func fetchFruits() {

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to return 1 in numberOfSectionsInTableView

Comment: Are you setting the table delegate in the storyboard or somewhere in code? You must.

Comment: @derdida: Yeah return non zero works fine. My bad it's a simple mistake. Thank you so much. Plus one for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to

```
return 1
```

in

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView.
```

Comment: why for god's sake did apple set the default value to 0 ?!? But thank you for that answer

Answer (score 2):

I will advise  you to simply create the master-detail application project and look at the tableviewcontroller code.

After pasting your code on Xcode, there are a few small issues.

```
import UIKit //1. remember to import UIKit for UITableViewController

//2. Do not return a UITableView! Instead, return a UITableView (without !) 
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0 // you should probably return 1 
    }

//3.Same as above. remove ! from UITableView, NSIndexPath and UITableViewCell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.description
        return cell
    }
```

And Lastly, you are missing an ending } for "class FriutsTableViewController: UITableViewController {"